# Solr indexing on multiple attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

I am struggling a bit in finding a solution to a situation where, I am trying to index attachments based on associations.

To explain it in more detail:

```
Model: job.rb
has_many :job_attachments
attachment :document_attachment, :multiple=>true
def document_attachment
    job_attachments.map do |j|
        "#{Rails.root}/public/#{j.attachment.url}"
    end
end
```

```
Model job_attachment.rb
belongs_to :job
has_attached_file :attachment,
  :url  => "/system/attachment/:job_id/:basename.:extension"
```

After this, whenever I run rake sunspot:reindex, my documents are not getting indexed also not getting any errors as well. The rake task is executing successfully. Am I doing something wrong here? Please suggest.

Comment: Hi Everyone,
I'm able to resolve this issue. PF updated code by following the pastie:

http://pastie.org/7267096

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the Solr gem handles it, but Solr Extract Handler provided support for only one attachment per document (unless changed in 4.X)

Solr does allow zip files to be indexed ([patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2416)), which would index the contents for the files.
So you can package the files into a zip and feed it Solr, which would be indexed as a Single document.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra for the response, I resolved the issue by doing some changes in the code base. See: http://pastie.org/7267096